# Trying to update table in mysql 8 gives error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update a table that I am working with.

Here is the "describe table;" output:

```
MySQL [mydb]> describe ost_staff;
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type                                      | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+-------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| staff_id               | int unsigned                              | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dept_id                | int unsigned                              | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| role_id                | int unsigned                              | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| username               | varchar(32)                               | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| firstname              | varchar(32)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname               | varchar(32)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| passwd                 | varchar(128)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| backend                | varchar(32)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email                  | varchar(255)                              | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| phone                  | varchar(24)                               | NO   |     |         |                |
| phone_ext              | varchar(6)                                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| mobile                 | varchar(24)                               | NO   |     |         |                |
| signature              | text                                      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lang                   | varchar(16)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timezone               | varchar(64)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| locale                 | varchar(16)                               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| notes                  | text                                      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
***| isactive               | tinyint(1)                                | NO   | MUL | 1       |                |***
```

I am trying to update the ***field: isactive*** so I try the following command from one of the solutions that I found online:

```
UPDATE `ost_staff` SET `value`=0 WHERE `key`='isactive';
```

when I ran this command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'key' in 'where clause'
```

I am trying to change the value from 1 to zero  in "Default" field.

Comment: key and value not on the lists of columns

Comment: You UPDATE a column there is no column/field called key and there is no column/field called value.and there is no default field..please review update statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html and reread your course notes or whatever it is you are working from.

Comment: And you should have a look at the describe documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html for an explanation of the output from a describe

Answer (score 0):

The error message is self explanary...
There is no column `key` in your table.

The request should be something like

```
UPDATE `ost_staff` SET `isactive`=0 WHERE `staff_id`=XX;
```

or

```
UPDATE `ost_staff` SET `isactive`=0
```

to set 0 to all staff.

Comment: This is one of those annoying mysql documentation inconsistencies where the error message refers to column but Describe refers to Field..